# Asio Https onHandshake if http send 308

Tags: c++, openssl, boost-asio, asio

I have a Http server, I only want to receive HTTPS connections, and if I receive a HTTP connection I want to send a 308 and then close that connection.

```cpp
void HttpSession::onHandshake(boost::beast::error_code errorCode)
{
  if (!errorCode)
  {
    readHttps();
    return;
  }
  if (errorCode.value() == ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, ERR_GET_FUNC(ec.value()), SSL_R_HTTP_REQUEST))
    readHttp();
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when a HTTP connection is received, the socket becomes invalid, preventing me from sending the HTTP 308 response.

How can I handle this situation, to ensure that I can respond with a 308 status code and close the connection when a plain HTTP request is received?

Comment: You can't do this. It's inpossible. TLS will invalidate and close the connection before you can use it.

Comment: @user207421 Except it can be done if you take the effort to inspect the input without consuming it, which is not hard on [a buffered stream abstraction](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html). In fact it's a library feature in Beast. See my answer.

Comment: I have to wonder. Did you forget about t this question? Perhaps people commenting "that's impossible" wasn't the best strategy, even with the best intentions

Comment: Hello, I haven't forgotten! It's just that I don't have the time yet. I will try your solution as soon as possible ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beast Library implements `detect_ssl` and `async_detect_ssl` composed operations for this purpose. There's a documentation page:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations/detect_ssl.html

The Beast "flex server" example shows how to implement SSL detection and switch accordingly. You're then free to provide different responses on the non-SSL path.

Link: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/beast/example/advanced/server-flex/advanced_server_flex.cpp

Excerpt:

```
// Detects SSL handshakes
class detect_session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<detect_session>
{
    beast::tcp_stream stream_;
    ssl::context& ctx_;
    std::shared_ptr<std::string const> doc_root_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;

public:
    explicit
    detect_session(
        tcp::socket&& socket,
        ssl::context& ctx,
        std::shared_ptr<std::string const> const& doc_root)
        : stream_(std::move(socket))
        , ctx_(ctx)
        , doc_root_(doc_root)
    {
    }

    // Launch the detector
    void
    run()
    {
        // We need to be executing within a strand to perform async operations
        // on the I/O objects in this session. Although not strictly necessary
        // for single-threaded contexts, this example code is written to be
        // thread-safe by default.
        net::dispatch(
            stream_.get_executor(),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &detect_session::on_run,
                this->shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_run()
    {
        // Set the timeout.
        stream_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        beast::async_detect_ssl(
            stream_,
            buffer_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &detect_session::on_detect,
                this->shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_detect(beast::error_code ec, bool result)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "detect");

        if(result)
        {
            // Launch SSL session
            std::make_shared<ssl_http_session>(
                std::move(stream_),
                ctx_,
                std::move(buffer_),
                doc_root_)->run();
            return;
        }

        // Launch plain session
        std::make_shared<plain_http_session>(
            std::move(stream_),
            std::move(buffer_),
            doc_root_)->run();
    }
};
```